# Column name is not referencing in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I took transporse of a dataframe and give name 'District' to extra column get after transporse.

`df.index = pd.Index(['Active','Confirmed','Deceased','Recovered'],name='District')`
`finaldf=df.T`

My finaldf dataframe contains District column
After that when I am taking this `finaldf.District`

getting below error

*AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'District'*

Please help me on this

Comment: When you transpose column names become row indices

Comment: row indices doesn't contain district name but column contain district column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,3), columns=list('abc'))
```

Here is problem `District` is not column, by axis name, so you can select it by `df.index`:

```
finaldf1=df.T
print (finaldf1)
District    Active  Confirmed  Deceased  Recovered
a         0.716292   0.672918  0.559143   0.206168
b         0.448028   0.196304  0.831332   0.511764
c         0.048026   0.943950  0.339930   0.990788

print (finaldf1.columns)
Index(['Active', 'Confirmed', 'Deceased', 'Recovered'], dtype='object', name='District')

print (finaldf1.index)
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

print (finaldf1.index.name)
None

print (finaldf1.columns.name)
District
```

For column is necessary [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.index = pd.Index(['Active','Confirmed','Deceased','Recovered'],name='District') 


finaldf=df.T.rename_axis(index='District', columns=None).reset_index()
print (finaldf)
  District    Active  Confirmed  Deceased  Recovered
0        a  0.700793   0.722742  0.452414   0.507035
1        b  0.669347   0.853931  0.296660   0.370256
2        c  0.552846   0.609019  0.630620   0.138213
```

Comment: Thanks It's working.Could you please explain reason for failing my condition?